# slideToggle not working for .sibling method

Tags: javascript, jquery, siblings

I want to make hidden divs show when a title is clicked. I have chosen jQuery to do this with the slideToggle. I set the  to have a class of "clicker-2", and the div is class "skill-talk_holder" that has the content is set to be hidden by CSS. There are multiple divs with the class of "skill-talk_holder" so I have to use something that will only open one at a time, and not all of them when "clicker-2" is clicked.

However, the only thing that happens is the page reloads (by just going to the top, not with a new HTTP req).

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.clicker-2').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings('div').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="divider">
    <a href="#" class="clicker-2"><h3 class="title">Non-Coding Web Skills</h3></a>
</div>
<span class="spacer"></span>
<div class="skill-talk_holder">
    content content content
</div>
```

Comment: No sibling `div` for the clicked element. Use `$(this).parent().siblings('div.skill-talk_holder').slideToggle('slow');`

Comment: Im not certain of what you mean. Should it be something like ".next"?

Comment: `siblings('div')` will search for sibling element `div`. `$(this)` in  the click handler refer to the element that was clicked i.e. the anchor `.clicker-2`. As that anchor don't have any sibling the code will not find any element to slidetoggle. Use the code as shown in first comment.

Comment: The clicked element has no siblings to toggle. I guess you mean to target `,skill-talk_holder`. Do you have more of these elements in your actual html and do they all have the same class?

Comment: @Tushar that does not do it. It is the same thing happening. I am definitely calling jQuery in the head also.

Comment: yes @DelightedD0D there are a few divs with ".skill-talk_holder"

Comment: @Tushar there seems to be a weird encoding issue with the code in your comment above from when you pasted it maybe. See http://prntscr.com/cpyyx1 and this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3n45Lzyb/ re-writing that section does work as expected though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your comments, you could use `.nextAll()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('.clicker-2').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('.skill-talk_holder').slideUp('slow'); 
      $(this).parent().nextAll('.skill-talk_holder:eq(0)').slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
.skill-talk_holder {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="divider">
    <a href="#" class="clicker-2"><h3 class="title">Non-Coding Web Skills</h3></a>
</div>
<span class="spacer"></span>
<div class="skill-talk_holder">
    content content content
</div>

<div class="divider">
    <a href="#" class="clicker-2"><h3 class="title">Non-Coding Web Skills</h3></a>
</div>
<span class="spacer"></span>
<div class="skill-talk_holder">
    content content content
</div>

<div class="divider">
    <a href="#" class="clicker-2"><h3 class="title">Non-Coding Web Skills</h3></a>
</div>
<span class="spacer"></span>
<div class="skill-talk_holder">
    content content content
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. Firstly, I cannot use jQuery2.1.1 and secondly, all of the content will be in the same div as the <a href>. So the content will expand underneath each of the links, respectively.

Comment: @wizardbeard jQuery version can be changed, updated to use 1.11. As for your second point, if that is true, then your posted HTML is not correct. As you can see, there are no divs underneath your link ;)

Comment: Is the div class="skill-talk" not under the link?

Comment: No, you have no `class="skill-talk"` element at all. You have a `class="skill-talk_holder"` element, but it is the second sibling to the link's *parent*. Your link has no siblings

Comment: yes I stand corrected. Nonetheless, THAT div is what holds the content. It is set to hidden and must be shown when the a href w class "clicker-2" is clicked.

Comment: @wizardbeard That's exactly what the code above does. Does the example above not work for you?

Comment: No. It doesn't. The content should appear right under the link that is clicked as opposed to displaying somewhere after a series of three links.
It should be like what this code would do:
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clicker-2").click(function(){
        $(".skill-talk_holder").slideToggle();
    });
    });

So like this:
link is clicked
---Content is shown
another link is clicked
---more content is shown.

not
link1
link2
link3

content from link1

content from link2

content from link3

Comment: @wizardbeard can you make a jsFiddle showing the multiple links and content? or add them here. That way we can better understand what you mean

Comment: @wizardbeard take a look at my update, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I mean. Now I don't understand why it doesn't do this on my page. I don't know how to make a fiddle.

But this basically reloads my page at the top instead of slideToggle with the content open. Then I just have to scroll down to the section to see the content open. And it only works for one div, the first one with the class of skill-talk_holder

:-\

Comment: @wizardbeard see my edit above which adds `event.preventDefault();` The default action of a clicked link is to navigate to the link's href value. I think that may be what you are seeing, this will prevent that. Does that work on your end?

Comment: @wizardbeard please see my latest edit, I had a mistake in the previous edit and I think I get how your html is structured now

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I was looking for. Perhaps because I chose "next" and not ".nextAll" ? :-\
Nonetheless, I accepted your answer and upvoted it. Now I need to make it so the open ones close as any of the other's are clicked. I think I am able to pull that one off. That I would need to do binding of handlers for, yes?

Comment: @wizardbeard actually, see my update. Calling `$('.skill-talk_holder').slideUp('slow');` before you toggle the current one will handle that for you

Comment: That part I was able to bang out last night. Yes. Thanks again for showing where I was not doing correctly, and alternate approaches.

Answer (score 0):

it's just lacking of parent selector:

```
$(this).parents('.divider:first').siblings('div').slideToggle("slow");
```

Comment: simply `.parent()` would be more efficient.

Comment: This just reloads the page, and hides my div of "divider". And furthermore it does open the hidden div, but it opens ALL with that class, and i do not want that. I only want one div which is the immediate div that is hidden on page load, and should show after the clicked element is acted upon. I don't understand why it isnt working with the posted code.

Comment: I can't use DelightedDOD's code or any expounding upon it because it has the links separate from the content. I don't want that. The content must be under the link like so:
clicker-2
 ---HIDDEN CONTENT SHOWS.
another clicker-2
---HIDDEN CONTENT SHOWS AND CLOSES THE OTHERS THAT WERE OPEN